# Creating the react app issue with npm

Tags: reactjs

I tried creating the new react app and for that i have followed the reactjs command to install like npm install -g create-react-app. But its not working and i am getting the error as npm ERR! Cannot find module 'pseudomap'. So for that i have uninstalled the nodejs 3 times and installed freshly. But still no luck for me. Can anybody provide any solution for this.

See below screens:
[image]

Comment: According to https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache/issues/114 you should try deleting your `package-lock.json` files and `node-modules` and then run `npm install`

Comment: There is nothing created in my project folder. Btw where can i find the package-lock.json

Comment: might be this one help open your terminal with admin rights and then try to install again.

Comment: Issue got resolved. I have re-installed and deleted all the node_modules folder and AppData content then it got worked.